# Does anyone knows if this is possible to use Windscribe VPN + TOR + Polipo all together in Ubuntu?

Tags: vpn

As asked I would like to know if there is a way to use  Windscribe VPN + TOR + Polipo all together, or if this a specific possibility for some particulars VPN?
And if this is possible how to do?

I use unbuntu 18.04.3.

Comment: Set up a transparent proxy for your Tor

Comment: What a crazy proposition...

Answer (score 0):

[According to the Tor Project:](https://support.torproject.org/#faq-5)

> Can I use a VPN with Tor? Generally speaking, we don't recommend using
>   a VPN with Tor unless you're an advanced user who knows how to
>   configure both in a way that doesn't compromise your privacy.

To answer your question, maybe? It probably hasn't been tried as it would not be a best practice unless you already know how to use both.

You can find more detailed information about Tor + VPN at the [Tor wiki](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TorPlusVPN).

Comment: I ask it because weirdly when I use spiders (indexation robots) on a website with Tor, so another IP than mine, that's my whole local network who can be blocked. For instance my smartphone could not access it correctly until I use the 4G and not the wifi. I guess there is a leak in my identity.